# Error: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, zip, export

I try to export to zip my flutter file, it's exporting but I get this exception:

Error: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\name\Desktop\app2\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\firebase_core